# jQuery slideToggle command causing text link to move

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a simple jQuery script that slides a contact form up from the footer using slideToggle and a negative margin.

It all works OK functionally but there are some visual glitches, when the panel is sliding the text link jumps aronund a bit.  Also the borders I have set on the panel drop down during the animation process.

I have created a jsFiddle demonstrating my problem at http://jsfiddle.net/YdT9v/ - can anyone see whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/YdT9v/6/) fiddle. I did make some changes in CSS as follows:

1. added `position:absolute;` to `.contactformcontainer`
2. added `bottom:40px; position:absolute;` to `#contactform`

(You might need to change the number in `bottom` property)

http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/YdT9v/6/

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems to have done the trick.  When I try it on my test site, the letters drop in weight when the animation is happening, it doesnt do this on the fiddle.  Could it be a z-index issue?